# search result displayed in data grid view

Tags: .net

I've customer id, customer name, contact no, address, country name(drop down list). and after inserting the data into the sql database It will displaying in grid view. But my requirement is, I've search button and one text box. after entering the any character into the text box then I click the search button. The result will be display in grid view regarding the character entered into the search box(like google search box and search button). the search will be done based on customer name. And result will be displayed in grid view.

Comment: Difficult to give you a thorough answer without knowing the programming language or technologies and patterns to be used. (C#, VB, ADO, ASP, LINQ to SQL, MVVM or MVC

Answer (score 1):

Pass the text box value to the stored procedure/Query, Use like operator to filter the data.

```
 Select * from tablename where customername like @txt%
```